# Known algorithms for incremental longest common substring?

Tags: algorithm, logging, longest-substring

Longest common substring is a well-known problem. I'm interested in identifying common substrings in a set of strings that is growing over time.

Use case: suppose I'm emitting log messages inside a tight loop. Many logging libraries offer a flag for suppressing *duplicate* messages, but what about *similar* messages? Contrived example:

```rust
for file in files {
    if ! process_file(file) {
        warn!("Failed to process {}.", file);
    }
}
```

If `files` has, say O(1) elements, this is all well & good. If it has O(10^6) elements, I'd like to see something like this in the log files:

```
Failed to process abc000000.txt.
Failed to process abc000001.txt.
Failed to process abc000002.txt.
[Repeated 912345 times]
```

in my log file.

I'm picturing a logging implementation that keeps track of longest common substring between the current & last log messages. If it spikes, it begins tracking all subsequent log messages. If more than `n` consecutive log messages display similar longest common substrings, it stops emitting them & starts a count.

Any prior art, here?

Comment: Based entirely on the example that you gave, it seems that you are not really interested in the longest sub-string in general but rather in whether the string that you are about to write is similar to the previous one, which should be a lot easier to detect.

Comment: Sure, that's one way to go. Was just wondering what else was out there.